# How to access MATLAB's Current Folder History programmatically

Tags: matlab, command-line-interface, environment

Is it possible to access the Current Folder History of MATLAB using the Command Window?

I already searched for this multiple times on the internet as well as forums and the MATLAB help. But I could not find any solution for this.

Maybe it is possible to read the history data from the file where MATLAB stores it. But searching the MATLAB installation directory as well as the `userpath` I couldn't find the file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Current Folder History." Perhaps you can teach me what it is? Did you mean command history? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-history.html

Comment: I mean the element in MATLAB's main window, which displays the current working directory. It has the title "Current Folder" and has a dropdown button where the last visited directories (the "History") can be accessed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The history is stored in the prefdir:

```
edit ( fullfile ( prefdir, 'cwdHistory.m' ) )
```